# Borel lemma : wikipedia proof

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, proof-explanation

In the [proof of Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma#Proof), I don't understand why we use $\psi\left(\frac{t}{\epsilon_m}\right)$ for a sufficient small $\epsilon_m$ and not $\psi(t\cdot \epsilon_m)$, as you need to keep derivatives small enough to ensure convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have *small* supports of $t\mapsto \psi(t/\varepsilon_m)$.
Of course, the derivatives become large and you have to deal with this in the proof of Borel's lemma.